# How do I return the smallest value using a for loop?

Tags: string, for-loop, limit

I am given a limit, and I have to return the smallest value for n to make it true: 1+2+3+4+...+n >= limit. I feel like there's one thing missing, but I can't tell.

```
public int whenToReachLimit(int limit) {
 int sum = 0;

 for (int i = 1; sum < limit; i++) {
   sum = sum + i;
  }
 return sum;
}
```

The output would be:
1 : 1
4 : 3
10 : 4

Comment: Please post some examples of what you want for some inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You get avoid the loop to compute the sum of the *n* first integers, using:

[image: formula1]

Thus the inequality becomes:

[image: formula2]

Notice that the left-hand side is positive (if n is negative, the sum is empty) and strictly increasing. Notice also that you are looking for the first integer satisfying the inequality. The idea here is first to replace the inequality by an equality which will allow us to solve the equation for *n*. In a second step, the possibly non-integer solution will be rounder to the closest integer.

[image: formula3]

Solving this equation for *n* should give you two solutions. The negative one can be discarded (remember *n* is positive). That is:

[image: formula4]

Finally, let's round this solution to the closest integer that will also satisfy the inequality:

[image: formula5]

NB: it can be overkilled for small inputs

Comment: Aka `return (int) Math.ceil((-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * limit)) / 2);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I know exactly what you want to do. But I would recommend to make a "practice run".

```
If Limit = 0 the function returns 0
If Limit = 1 the function returns 1
If Limit = 2 the function return 3
If Limit = 3 the function return 3
If Limit = 4 the function return 6
If Limit = 5 the function return 6
```

Now you decide by your own if the functions does what you're expecting.

Comment: I forgot to add, the output would be: whenToReachLimit(1) -> 1 //whenToReachLimit(4) -> 3//whenToReachLimit(10) -> 4

Comment: I can only get the output for 1, but not for 4 and 10.

Comment: Sorry, but it's currently not clear for me, what the function should do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to return sum, you want to return n (smallest possible value satisfying the given requirement).

**return** `i-1` instead of `sum`.

Comment: But I can't return `i-1` when I have `int sum = 0`

Comment: When will the `sum` remain 0 after the `for` loop? Only if `limit` is 0.  If the `limit` is 0, you will end up returning (i-1) = 1-1 = 0 which is correct.

Comment: I don't know if you read my comment for the last person, but the output should be whenToReachLimit(1) -> 1 // whenToReachLimit(4) -> 3 // whenToReachLimit(10) -> 4

Comment: @DissolvedMan, see my edited answer now. It will return 4 for limit 10 and 5 for limit 11. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. Turns out it doesn't work with a `for` loop which I find odd. But this is the answer to my own question.

```
public int whenToReachLimit(int limit) {
int n = 0;
int sum = 0;

while (sum < limit) {
   sum += n;
   n++;
  }
 return n-1;
}
```

Comment: it can work with `for` loop if it works with `while`. See my answer again.